# exporting Bump and Specular maps

Tags: three.js, bump-mapping, specular

I have seen the new MeshPhongMaterial Bump and Specular highlights, and can't wait to get them into my game engine.
Currently i am using the python converter to convert an OBJ file into a .js file. However release 51 exporter doesn't seem to handle these materials.

I am also concerned that most of my meshes have 2 or more materials, and are using MeshFaceMaterial.

Will changing to MeshPhongMaterial break the multiple textures?
Should i use a different exporter to achieve this?
What is the best workflow to convert from .3ds files with Bump and Specular maps?
Should i wait a while for this topic to settle down?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you already use a diffuse texture (Lambert material perhaps?) and as such have also exported texture coordinates.

You can add `mapBump` and `mapSpecular` properties manually to the materials in question in the .js model file. They are strings pointing to the textures just like `mapDiffuse`. Also change the `shading` property to "Phong", and you should be good to go, though you might also want to tweak `specularCoef` and `colorSpecular` material properties.

Simply switching material type won't break the face materials.

Comment: well this is a follow up to my previous post, i managed to get the bump map to work, now i have an Illumination map too, but havent found a field for that yet, any ideas? When you mentioned the "shading" parameter, should it be set to "shading":"THREE.SmoothShading" ?